# logger throws exception in grails 4 in printing object

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am sending error to users depends on exception i write the logic in loadUserByUsername in my service class

```
def generalUser = AdminUser.findByUser(user) ?: StoreUser.findByUser(user)
        if (generalUser.userStatuses != UserStatuses.ACTIVE) {
            if (generalUser.userStatuses == UserStatuses.PENDING_CONFIRMATION)
                throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException('string')
            else if (generalUser.userStatuses == UserStatuses.PENDING_STORE_APPROVAL)
                throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException('For User approval is pending by store admin.')
           }
```

whenever the throw line executed in above code if block the debugger goes to **AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java** and then in logger.error error is printed in console

```
catch (InternalAuthenticationServiceException failed) {
        logger.error(
                "An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.",
                failed);
        unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: What is it that you would like to be able to do?

Comment: Can you tell which class is being imported on logger? You can use org.apache.commons.logging.Log interface has method void error(Object message, Throwable t) (and method void info(Object message, Throwable t)), which logs the stack trace together with your custom message.

Comment: That's the interface being used in the java class.  What error are you seeing?  What are you trying to accomplish?  It's still not clear what problem you're encountering.

Comment: Actually whenever i am trying to login with a user whose profile is pending i want to show the error that your profile is not confirmed yet and it is working from above code
But in console the stacktrace error is printing whenever i am throwing the exception this is because when i am debugging the code then the control goes to spring security class AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter in which there is a line logger.error() from this point exception is printed to console